# strange behavior of Coroutine

Tags: python, coroutine

I'm learning about Coroutine but it work strange that I can't understand...
Here's the source

```
@coroutine
def printer():
    tmp=(yield)
    print tmp

def sender(coru):
    coru.send("hello")
    print "I'm sender"

if __name__=="__main__":
    coru=printer()
    sender(coru)
    print "I'm master"
```

shows

> hello
>
> StopItertationError @ coru.send("hello")

while,

```
@coroutine
def printer():
          while 1:
               tmp=(yield)
               print tmp

def sender(coru):
    coru.send("hello")
    print "I'm sender"

if __name__=="__main__":
    coru=printer()
    sender(coru)
    print "I'm master"
```

shows

> hello
>
> I'm sender
>
> I'm master

correctly.

So I'm wondering

1. why coroutine always work with the loops and why the first example rise error
2. I heared about 'yield from' syntax at version 3.3. Is that help to make the first one work?
3. I know every coroutine function work equivalently unlike the subroutines.

   but then, I think, after the Printer function ends, the program should be terminated without returning to Sender.

   but it does. doesn't it means that sender superior to printer? what is the difference between subroutine and coroutine then.

thanks for reading and I really appreciate if you enlight me:)

Comment: about @coroutine. It's just wrapper to automate func.next() to make coroutine ready

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a generator (like `printer`) ends, it raises a StopIteration exception.

When Python executes

```
coru.send("hello")
```

it jumps to

```
tmp = (yield)
```

and assigns "hello" to `tmp`. It then executes the next line:

```
print tmp
```

and then the generator ends, thus raising the `StopIteration` exception.

If, on the other hand, you do not allow `printer` to end (by using a `while 1` loop) then the `StopIteration` exception is never raised. Instead execution (in `printer`) continues until the next `yield` expression is reached:

```
tmp = (yield)
```

The `send` method returns the value of that `yield` expression (in this case, `None`). At this point, Python has once again returned to the `sender` function and next executes

```
print "I'm sender"
```

---

The purpose of the `yield from` syntax is to make it easier to refactor generators (intended to be used with `send` and `throw`) into subgenerators. [See PEP380](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) and [What's New in Python3](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380-syntax-for-delegating-to-a-subgenerator).

It doesn't change the StopIteration behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very nice introduction to coroutines :

http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/

In particular, you can have a look at :

http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/grep.py

and (exemple @coroutine implementation) :

http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/coroutine.py